# Auditing with Hibernate Envers: How to Query When ID is not 'id'

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

With Hibernate Envers, you create a corresponding auditing table with a suffix of "_AUD" for each of your JPA entities and then you can query using `AuditReader`.

This AuditReader assumes that the ID of the Entity is **id** and that it has a **getId()** getter. In my case, all off my entities have differently named identifiers like **userId** and **accountId**, etc... all with varying dataTypes.

How can I create a pattern that reduces boilerplate code to retrieve auditing history data by id without knowing the fieldName of the id?

Comment: How is AuditReader assuming that the ID of the entity is **id** ?

Answer (score 0):

That is what `AuditEntity.id()` is for :)

```
AuditQuery query = getAuditReader()
    .forRevisionsOfEntity( MyEntity.class. true, false )
    .add( AuditEntity.id().eq( myEntityClassId ) );
```

You shouldn't need to know what *property* maps to your entity's identifier property because Envers will handle all the necessary equality / inequality checks between types and property mappings behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

what about ?

```
getAuditReader().createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEntity.class, false, false).add( AuditEntity.property("accountId").eq(12));
```